# Add data to the end of a column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, button

I been trying to figure this out for so long but no avail.
Basically in column A there will a variable list of ID's. I need a way that copies this list of ID's and pastes it to column B but adds 3 more rows at the end, one saying "POS" next "NEG" and lastly "IND" so it looks like.

Note that column A will always be changing in length, so sometimes there will be 5 IDs and other times there might be 12 (never more than 17).
I need a macro code that I can make a button that will copy all the list in A then add the 3 extra numbers into column B.

Thank you so much!
A

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| X123 | X123 |
| Y123 | Y123 |
| Z123 | Z123 |
|  | POS |
|  | NEG |
|  | IND |

Answer (score 1):

You can count the rows in column A  copy it into column B and then add the POS/NEG/IND. Just like this:

```
Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Row, 1)).Copy
Cells(1, 2).Select 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Cells(Row + 1, 2) = "POS"
Cells(Row + 2, 2) = "NEG"
Cells(Row + 3, 2) = "IN"
```